# Why web API Action method returning Json of child properties even after casting it's parent class

Tags: c#, json, serialization, casting, asp.net-web-api2

I have web api controller like this:

```
public class ParentController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetParent()
    {
        //instatiating child class
        var child = new Child
        {
            ChildProp1 = "childValue1",
            ChildProp2 = "childValue2",
            ParentProp1 = "parentValue1",
            ParentProp2 = "parentValue2"
        };

        //up casting is implicit
        Parent parent = child;

        //returning parent as Json http request
        return Ok(parent);
    }

    private class Child : Parent
    {
        public string ChildProp1 { get; set; }
        public string ChildProp2 { get; set; }
    }

    private class Parent
    {
        public string ParentProp1 { get; set; }
        public string ParentProp2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and it works perfectly except it return Json result of both parent and child properties and What I need is **only properties of parent class**

Output response body:

```
{
    "childProp1": "childValue1",
    "childProp2": "childValue2",
    "parentProp1": "parentValue1",
    "parentProp2": "parentValue2"
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your not casting it, you're assigning the child object to a reference of Parent object. It's still a child object underneath. The serialisation class obviously understands this.

Comment: If you need only the properties of the parent class, then why are you creating a child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You could return an anonymous type

   `return Ok(new { ParentProp1 = parent.ParentProp1, ParentProp2 = parent.ParentProp2 });`
2. You could add the `JsonIgnore` attribute to the `Child` properties (though this would mean that you wont be able to return them as JSON in other pieces of code.)

   ```
   [JsonIgnore]
   public string ChildProp1 { get; set; }

   [JsonIgnore]
   public string ChildProp2 { get; set; }
   ```
3. You could create an interface `IParent` with only the parent properties `ParentProp1` and `ParentProp2` and then use a custom contract resolver (as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123821/serialize-only-interface-properties-to-json-with-json-net)) with `JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver` to tell it to serialize only the interface properties.

   ```
   return Json(parent, new JsonSerializerSettings {
     ContractResolver = new InterfaceContractResolver (typeof(IParent))
   });
   ```

**Option #3** is probably the best because unlike Option #1 you would only have to redefine your properties in the interface instead of possibly in multiple `HttpGet` methods that return anonymous types.  Also, unlike Option #2, you wouldn't be restricted from returning your child properties as JSON from other `HttpGet` methods.

Comment: Thanks for extended answer. I agree with with on choosing option #3. but after testing it the response body in PostMan now looks like this `{\"ParentProp1\":\"parentValue1\",\"ParentProp2\":\"parentValue2\"}`. I haven't test it on real client yet but why it has different format compare to default format in my post?

Comment: @BehzadBahmanyar Try returning from your `GetParent` method using `return Json(parent, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = ... })`.  If you return it as a string through the `Ok` method then it is probably using the default serializer and not the JSON.NET one.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Although you are casting it, the instance is still actually a `Child` so when the JSON serializer does `parent.GetType()` it ends up with `Child` and gets the properties of `Child`.

If you want the result to **just** be the properties of `Parent` then you need to just create an instance of `Parent` to start with.

Comment: He's not casting it, casts are always explicit. An implicit conversion isn't a cast

Comment: @Liam you're wrong, copy that code into a console app and do `parent.GetType()` and it'll return `Child` - it isn't doing a conversion it's doing a cast

Comment: You mean instantiate the Parent then map the child properties one by one to it Or use libraries like automapper for mapping.is there any other way?

Comment: @BehzadBahmanyar or just create the parent initially, why create the child if you only care about the parent?

Comment: Because technicality all of of parent properties are in it's child too.

Comment: Yes but if you don't need the extra properties of `Child` why are you creating a `Child`?

Comment: Consider I have a method with Child return type that is called from two part of server. In one part I need to use the Child properties too but in the other part I only need the Parent props.

Comment: your missing my point, your answer is right, but this isn't a cast per se, [Explicit conversions (casts): Explicit conversions require a cast operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx). A cast is a conversion, not every conversion is a cast

Comment: @Liam - this is not a conversion because the underlying object isn't converted from a `Child` to a `Parent` it's just the variable that is changed if you did `Parent parent = (Parent)child;` it would behave exactly the same as it does here.