# How to serialize a castle dynamic proxy interface using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net, castle-dynamicproxy

I have a number of proxies for my application's interface (let's call it `IConfig`) that were generated using Castle DynamicProxy and populated with all the right values. The proxy objects are of type `Castle.Proxies.IConfigProxy`. When I try to serialise these proxies to JSON, using Newtonsoft.Json, I expect to get a JSON matching the properties defined for an `IConfig`:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(proxy);
```

However, I instead get a string with the internal workings of the proxy and none of the data contained in the `IConfig`:

```
{
    "__interceptors": [{}],
    "__target": null,
    "__interfaces": [],
    "__baseType": "System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "__proxyGenerationOptions": {
        "hook": {},
        "selector": null,
        "mixins": null,
        "baseTypeForInterfaceProxy.AssemblyQualifiedName": "System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
    },
    "__proxyTypeId": "interface.without.target",
    "__targetFieldType": "System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
    "__theInterface": "MyNamespace.IConfig, MyAssembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
}
```

The original issue I encountered was with dynamic proxies generated using the Config.Net NuGet package. However, I have now recreated a minimal reproducible sample in LINQPad using Moq. Here is some sample code that generates a similar result:

```
void Main()
{
    var config = new Mock<IConfig>();
    config.Setup(x => x.Key).Returns("test");
    var proxy = config.Object;
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(proxy, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    json.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public interface IConfig
{
    string Key { get; set; }
}
```

For this particular issue I am using .NET Framework 4.8 with the latest versions of Json.NET (and in the case of the sample code Moq).

Can someone please help explain this behaviour and show me a way to translate these objects to JSON?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you serialize with System.Text.Json?

Comment: That works actually, thanks! Feel free to suggest it as an answer! So I guess this is a problem in the way that Json.NET reads the proxy objects.

Comment: System.Text.Json serializes only the declared properties of that specific reference, unless declared as `object`.  I bet if you did `JsonSerializer.Serialize((object)proxy)` then System.Text.Json would behave like Json.NET.  But Json.NET serializes the actual properties of the object itself, not the declared properties of the reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The cause of your problem** is that, when you serialize a reference of declared type `IConfig` to an object of some concrete type with Json.NET:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject<IConfig>(IConfig proxy);
```

Json.NET will determine the actual, concrete type of the object by calling `proxy.GetType()`, and then serialize all the properties of that concrete type -- and there may be many more than for the declared type of the reference.  (I.e. the declared type `IConfig` is not actually used).

To debug this, you may use Json.NET's [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_serialization_defaultcontractresolver.htm) to dump the properties that will actually get serialized:

```
var contract = (new DefaultContractResolver()).ResolveContract(proxy.GetType());
Console.WriteLine(proxy.GetType());
if (contract is JsonObjectContract objContract)
    foreach (var property in objContract.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", property.UnderlyingName, property.PropertyType);
```

This results in:

```
Castle.Proxies.IConfigProxy
  Key: System.String
  Mock: Moq.Mock
  Moq.IMocked`1[IConfig].Mock: Moq.Mock`1[IConfig]
  Interceptor: System.Object
```

It's those extra properties that are causing the problem.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/csoIub).

**As a workaround** you could switch to the builtin serializer System.Text.Json, which does serialize only the properties of the declared type of the reference, unless the declared type is `object`<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize<IConfig>(
            proxy, 
            new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UaBZbA).

**Alternatively**, you could investigate using one of the answers from *[Serialize only interface properties to JSON with Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17123821/3744182)* to serialize your proxy -- but using the builtin serializer seems simpler.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> For confirmation see *[How to serialize properties of derived classes with System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/polymorphism)*.